# why does io:get_line return "\n" in erlang shell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

when using io:getline("prompt") in the erlang shell , the function returns immediately with a return value of "\n"

```
io:get_line("prompt"). 
prompt
"\n"
```

but as suggested in another thread doing the following reads from standard_io correctly.

```
spawn(fun() -> timer:sleep(100),io:get_line("prompt") end).
```

waits for user input and reads from standard io (shell). It was mentioned that it was a race condition . can anyone tell me why is it so and how is it possible to read a value from the erlang shell ?

Comment: I have no idea but on my computer it works as intended. Maybe you should give additional info about your installation and architecture

Comment: I agree with @niahoo.

Comment: ubuntu 13.04 on amd64 erlang r15b01 smp emabled

Answer (score 2):

**io:get_line/1** and **io:get_line/2** returns data with **\n** every time.

`get_line(Prompt) -> Data | server_no_data()`

Where:

> Data
>
> **The characters in the line terminated by a LF** (or end of file). If the
>   IO device supports Unicode, the data may represent codepoints larger
>   than 255 (the latin1 range). If the I/O server is set to deliver
>   binaries, they will be encoded in UTF-8 (regardless of if the IO
>   device actually supports Unicode or not).

In first case you got **\n**, and try to get result of `io:get_line` in second case:

```
spawn(fun() -> 
      timer:sleep(100), 
      Result = io:get_line("prompt"), 
      io:format("Result: ~p~n", [Result]) 
end).
```

Comment: i understood why it returns "\n" . My question is why doesn't case 1 wait for a user a input and instead returns immediately.

Comment: `io:get_line()` will be used the way above only in command line, otherwise, if you want to use it in your application or module, you will have to make it like this `io:get_line(File_descriptor,"")`, and it should return the contents of the current line, where each line is terminated by a line feed or `\n`,put it in a for loop, to read your file line by line

Answer (score 0):

**Let's break it down...**

**Why `io:get_line/1` returns a `\n`?**

`io:get_line/1` returns a "line" and a `\n` ("end of a line" or "new line") constitutes a line together with the string you entered.

```
> io:get_line("Prompt:").
Prompt:TheStringIEntered
"TheStringIEntered\n"
```

**How to read a value from the Erlang shell?**

```
> Data = string:strip(io:get_line("Prompt:"), right, $\n).
Prompt:TheStringIEntered
"TheStringIEntered"
> Data.
"TheStringIEntered"
```

Note that the value (Data) here is always of string type. You can convert it into other types, but you always start with a string.

**Why does `spawn(fun() -> timer:sleep(100),io:get_line("prompt") end).` behave differently?**

Because `spawn` spawns a new process that temporarily takes over the shell. Once this process gets `TheStringIEntered`, it also reaches the end of its life. So it dies without having its return value (`TheStringIEntered`) printed to the shell.

Comment: i am sorry . I dont think I made myself clear. I understand how to use io:get_line. but when using it on my computer this is the behaviour that happens
    `3> Data = io:get_line("Prompt:").                           
     Prompt:
     "\n"
     4>`
The REPL waits for you to enter a string and then returns it. But in my case , after calling io:get_line() i am unable to enter a string , the prompt is printed and then the return value is just a \n . I wanted to know why that happens .

Comment: @draklor40 Try compiling Erlang from source.